# How to send the selected option from a select_tag to an onchange javascript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, onchange, html-select

I have a select_tag that, when changed, calls a javascript method using onchange.

I would like the value of the option selected in the select_tag to be sent as a parameter to the method.

```
<%= link_to_function select_tag :search_type, options_for_select(search_type_options, @search_type), :onchange => "showSearchables( **the option selected ** );return false;" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without JQuery, you can change *the option selected* to:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

Answer (score 1):

If using JQuery, you can use

```
:onchange => "showSearchables($(this).val());"
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of HTML/JavaScript, this is pretty straight-forward:

```
<form>
  <select onChange="getVal( this )">
    <option>one</option>
    <option>two</option>
    <option>three</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function getVal( oSelect ) 
  {
    var selectedValue = oSelect.options[ oSelect.selectedIndex ].value;
  }
</script>
```